# How to give the next highest dialog focus after closing another dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a situation where a user is able to open multiple independent dialogs. Intuitively, the dialog that has focus can be closed either by using the x icon or by pressing ESC.

After this dialog is closed, can the next dialog (based on the highest z-index) be given focus, so that the user could continue pressing ESC to close all their open dialogs?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt9YM/1/). After loading, select any dialog, which you should be able to close by pressing ESC. The next highest dialog doesn't get focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `close` event occurs, check for the `div.ui-dialog` that is visible (closing a `.ui-dialog` will simply hide the element) and has the highest `z-index`. Then set the focus on that dialog. This may not be the most efficient, but will work:

```
// ...
close: function() {            
    var index_highest = 0;
    var current_dialog = null;
    $('.ui-dialog').each(function() {
        // we only care about dialogs that are visible
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            // always use a radix when using parseInt
            var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
            if(index_current > index_highest) {
                index_highest = index_current;
                current_dialog = $(this);
            }
        }
    });
    if (current_dialog) { current_dialog.focus(); }
}
// ...
```

[An updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPafH/). Credit [justkt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680815) regarding finding the element with the highest z-index using jQuery.