# drag and drop jquery not working between div tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a left column which stores "panels" which can be dragged onto the main content area of the page. Dragging a panel to a new "area" in the left column works fine, but if I try to drag it into the main content area it seems to go behind it, even using z-index. I created the following to illustrate: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HQt6/1/)

FYI  there will be more areas in the main content area to drag to, I just kept it simple for the purposes of this thread. Also in my application the panels are in fact Kendo graphs which require the !important tag to be used on some styling.

Can anyone help?

JScript:

```
$('.area').droppable({
tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('.panel').draggable({
revert: 'invalid',
stop: function () {
    $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
}
});

$('.panel').droppable({
greedy: true,
tolerance: 'touch',
drop: function (event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.area {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid silver;
background-color:yellow;
padding:10px;
z-index: 10;
}
.panel {
display:inline-block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid silver;
background-color:white;
}
#frameContentLeft {
position: absolute !important;
top: 0px !important;
left: 0px !important;
width: 200px !important;
height: 1000px !important;
background-color: blue;
}
#mainContent {
position: absolute !important;
left: 200px !important;
top: 0px !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: 1000px !important;
background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frameContentLeft">
    <div class="area">
        <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="area">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mainContent">
    <div class="area"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the z-index of the element you are moving...

http://jsfiddle.net/8HQt6/3/

I just set the z-index of `.panel` to 11 and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, I had meant to do this earlier, but in my code I had put it under area instead of panel by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I found out as a problem is that your mainContent z-index is higher than the other panes, try doing something like:

```
#mainContent {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 200px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 1000px !important;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Or increasing the z-index of the element you are moving. **(Remember that by doing it, you are going to get the same error once you add more divs with higher z-index)**

In case you want to dinamically change z-index, you may try to refer to: [How to find the highest z-index using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680770/jquery-find-the-highest-z-index)

- Get the higher z-index
- and then set this z-index + 1 to the draggable element.

Comment: Thank you!
Can you explain why the mainContent was automatically getting a higher z-index than the others without me setting it?

Comment: It's higher because it was defined in the HTML after the `.panel` div. 
If it was defined earlier like: 
`<div id="mainContent"> ...</div><div id="frameContentLeft"> ... </div>` then it would have a lower z-index. That's why when you put another 15 divs, the z-index is going to be higher than 11. It will fail again.

If your code will be always like that, everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense now and I can keep this in mind for future development. I appreciate your time.