# How to put element on top of all other elements withouth using explicit number for z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

I have an element `E` which works as a pop-up windows. When I open this windows I want it to be displayed on top of everything else. E.g. if there are multiple pop-up windows open, my particular element `E` should be on top of everything else.

I'm familiar with the `z-index` but this approach sounds very buggy. If someone else uses a higher `z-index` my pop up windows will vanish in the background.

How can I prevent this from happening? Is there an attribute which declares an element to be always on top?

Comment: If you do not want to use `z-index` then declare your element as the last element with CSS positioning to show it above other elements. It is not necessary that a higher z-index will hide you pop-up windows always. A higher z-index works only if your pop-up window and other elements are in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: If there was an "X property: always display on top", people would be asking for a "show slightly higher than X".

Comment: @DBS That sounds very true.

Comment: *Is there an attribute which declares an element to be always on top?* --> it's z-index with a *very* big value. As simple as that

Comment: Do you have control over the other pop ups? Is it you that display them?

Comment: There is nothing buggy with z-index. It's working perfectly in every way intended. A way to have something be on top of something else is to simply give it a higher z-index than every other element. There's no hocus pocus to it. It's literally just that. No bugs. Pretty much every pop-up utlizes this.

Comment: If you do encounter problems with z-index, it's because your logic is wrong (which would be easier to tell if you incorporated some code in your question). For instance, a parent can never be on top of its child. The child will have a z-index relative to its parent.

Comment: @Martin Of course `z-index` isn't buggy. However, the solution may lead to bugs/unwanted behavior which will be hard to debug. I was just curious if there's another way of achieving the same solution. But it seems like that `z-index` is the appropriate way.

Comment: @mahan I have control of my Element `E`. The other pop-ups are loaded from a variety of scripts. Hence, I can't control them.

Comment: Find the hightest z-index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680770/how-to-find-the-highest-z-index-using-jquery Pop ups normally direct descendents of body.