# How to put img in front of svg tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, snap.svg

I'm using snap.svg
I have index.html

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MAP_TEST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "JS/init.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "JS/snap.svg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="comm_cont">
        <div id = "svgborder">
            <svg id = 'svgmain'></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And init.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var s = Snap("#svgmain");
    var g = s.group();
    Snap.load("SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg",function(lf)
    {
        g.append(lf);
        //trying to load picture... Scale button in future
        $('<img />', {
                src: 'PNG/plus.png',
                width: '30px',
                height: '30px',
                id: 'buttoninrk'
        }).appendTo($('.comm_cont'));
        //this button must be on picture
        //but in front of the picture svg element
        //And i can't click the button
    });
});
```

I played with z-indexes of **#svgborder** and **#buttoninkr** but it didn't help me.
How to put button in front of svg element?

```
#buttoninkr, #svgborder
{
    position: absolute;
}
#svgborder
{
    border:5px solid black;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#buttoninkr
{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Added css code with z-indexes.
There is a reason why i'm not using svg buttons instead jquery image button.

**Ok, as you can see #svgmain in front of plus.png** 
 http://jsfiddle.net/3wcq9aad/1/

Any ideas?

Solved

```
 #svgborders
  {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #535364;
      border:5px solid black;
      z-index: 0;
      margin-left:auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
 #buttoninrk, #buttondekr, #home_btn
 {
     position: inherit;
     top:0;
     margin:10px;
     z-index: 1;
 }
 #buttoninrk
 {
     right:0px;
 }
 #buttondekr
 {
     right:60px
 }
```

Comment: It seems like a CSS position issue. Can you provide the CSS which is related to this page? BTW, there is a wrong tag mapping in the HTML (head tag with closing body tag?).

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just adding it via Snap into the main paper ? A jsfiddle would be useful to highlight. Normally its the order of objects in the DOM which matters, and not quite sure why it wouldn't be at the front (maybe the position of comm_cont.

Comment: Corrected my post. Added css.

Comment: Reason why i don't use snap to load because a want to separate svg element and controll elements.

Comment: Is it possible to post the bits on a fiddle to have a play with ?

Comment: Ok, as you can see #svgmain in front of plus.png
http://jsfiddle.net/3wcq9aad/1

Comment: svg does not support z-index$('element').css('position', 'absolute');

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233219/is-there-a-way-in-jquery-to-bring-a-div-to-front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** It wasn't the position of the div that made the difference, but simply adding a width and height. So the original HTML works fine as long as you add a width and height to `svgborder` in the CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wcq9aad/4/

(Note that sometimes, the position of an element within a document *can* make a difference to how z-index works.)

---

If you put the `svgborder` div before the svg, then z-index will work, but you'll need to know the width and height of your SVG and set it on the `svgborder` div.

```
<body>
    <div class="comm_cont">
        <div id="svgborder"></div>
        <svg id='svgmain'></svg>
    </div>
</body>

#svgborder
{
    z-index: 2;
    width:330px;
    height:150px;
    ...
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3wcq9aad/3/

Comment: I'm not sure this is what i wanted, because it looks like you add plus.png near the svg element, but i want it to bo on the svg element.
You have this http://i66.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0813/c2/bea13e24e7c7863dada445c650f869c2.jpg
I need this http://i66.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0813/61/9d1004e419d9b6a2da985293ed760b61.jpg

Comment: The #svgborder element is definitely in front of the svg in my example; to verify this, give #svgborder a background color and you'll see it completely covers the svg. It sounds like you're having trouble getting your svg to display the way you want, which is a separate question - you might want to create a new question about that (plus I don't know much about svg).

Answer (score 0):

svg does not support z-index
Use element position instead:
$('element').css('position', 'absolute');

[Is there a way in jQuery to bring a div to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233219/is-there-a-way-in-jquery-to-bring-a-div-to-front)